# Am I allowed to call someone a kook?

Tags: discussion, comments, ethics

Is it against the rules to call someone a kook?

Comment: It’s hard to see how that would comply with any conceivable be-nice policy.

Comment: No name-calling. Just downvote and/or vote to close questions that don’t make sense or aren’t mainstream physics.

Comment: Honestly, this question itself probably violates the Be Nice policy.

Comment: @Chris Good point. I've fixed that with an edit.

Comment: You can, of course, criticize the ideas you find objectionable if you think it will do any good. But keep it impersonal and focused on what is wrong.

Comment: You can say it in a subtle way which focuses on the content of the post: "This post is regarding _extremely_ non-mainstream physics" will help reviewers and convey the same meaning.

Comment: Old discussion of this: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/340/50583

Comment: While I understand that very minimal effort would have led the OP to the SE Be-Nice policy, I don't really understand why this is downvoted to hell. We got a user who actually wanted to find out whether the site policy allows name-calling and putting down, before resorting to this. Can't we just make them aware of the policy, and leave it at that? It is a perfectly legitimate question IMO.

Comment: @299792458 Originally it called out a specific question, so as mentioned, may have violated the policy itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this would go against the Stack Exchange [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) (also known as the "Be-Nice" policy).

To quote from it:

> **No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language.**
>
> **No name-calling or personal attacks.**

I would say this falls under both, so it definitely violates the policy.

Comment: Furthermore, if you notice such content on the site, please flag as "rude" to bring it to the attention of the moderators.